# in this example, what is the third missing possibility for the try block?

Tags: java, try-catch, function-try-block

```
public void writeList() {
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("Entering" + " try statement");

        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("OutFile.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IndexOutOfBoundsException: "
                           +  e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " +  e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
            out.close();
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
        }
    }
}
```

This method's try block has three different exit possibilities; here are two of them.

1) Code in the try statement fails and throws an exception. This could be an IOException caused by the new FileWriter statement or an IndexOutOfBoundsException caused by a wrong index value in the for loop.

2) Everything succeeds and the try statement exits normally.

Could someone tell me, what is the third potential possibility that could happen but is not mentioned here?

Comment: Some other runtime exception or error is thrown and escalates upwards?

Comment: I change my answer.  What if SIZE is larger than an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception can be propagated to the next method in the stack